# find record between date slab(range)

Tags: sql, date

I created a table in which I have entered the rates of hotels with dates from which date to which date those rates are valid. What i want in another form if i select a particular date in the rates for particular hotel should be displayed for specific date that falls under whichever slab of dates because every date slab have different hotel rates

I have tried this

```
select * from test_hotelrates where Datefrom >= convert(date, '2013-10-01', 103) 
and Dateto <= convert(date, '2013-10-31', 103) and Season = 'Season'
```

but it doesn't work as per my need

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you use 2 different dates to compare with. In this example you want the rate for all the days of October. I assume someone wants to stay a full month at a hotel. But I think you want to check every single day in that time period, for the current rate. Because in that period the rates can change.

Your query will only return rates that are WITHIN the timeframe 10-01-2013 to 10-31-2013.

I think you will need to make a different query or run this one multiple times

```
select * from test_hotelrates where Datefrom <= convert(date, '2013-10-01', 103) 
and Dateto >= convert(date, '2013-10-01', 103) and Season = 'Season'

select * from test_hotelrates where Datefrom <= convert(date, '2013-10-02', 103) 
and Dateto >= convert(date, '2013-10-02', 103) and Season = 'Season'

select * from test_hotelrates where Datefrom <= convert(date, '2013-10-03', 103) 
and Dateto >= convert(date, '2013-10-03', 103) and Season = 'Season'
```

Etc...

Answer (score 0):

Change your query as below:

```
select * from test_hotelrates where convert(varchar(10),Datefrom,103) >= convert(varchar(10), '2013-10-01', 103) 
and convert(varchar(10),Dateto,103) <= convert(varchar(10), '2013-10-31', 103) and Season = 'Season'
```

as both formats should be same. Hope this will work for you